# Run bash while loop in Python

Tags: python, bash, python-3.x, while-loop, subprocess

I am trying to run a `bash` while loop inside a `Python3.6` script. What I have tried so far is:

```
subprocess.run(args=['while [ <condition> ]; do <command> done;'])
```

I get the following error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Is there a way to run such a while loop inside `Python`?

Comment: Welcome to SO: Please take the [tour] and read with attention [MCVE]. Show us your code that we can help you.

Comment: This is missing a [`shell=True`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) keyword argument. As is, you are trying to execute a binary with the name of the passed in string`. And note that I have never seen any need for this.

Comment: `while` is no program, it is a bash builtin command. Try `bash -c "while ..."`

Comment: Thanx @dhke that worked.

Comment: The argument you should pass is `['/bin/bash', '-c', ' .. your code ..']`. That way you can control stdout and stderr if you need.

Comment: Why are you shelling out to run a loop instead of just looping in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part that's tripping you up is providing the args as a list.  From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#replacing-functions-from-the-popen2-module):

> If the cmd argument to popen2 functions is a string, the command is executed through /bin/sh. If it is a list, the command is directly executed.

This seems to do what you want:

```
subprocess.run('i=0; while [ $i -lt 3 ]; do i=`expr $i + 1`; echo $i; done', shell=True)
```

Notice it's specified as a string instead of a list.

Answer (score 1):

Running bash `for loop` in `Python 3.x` is very much like running `while` loop.

```
#! /bin/bash

for i in */;
do
    zip -r "${i%/}.zip" "$i";
done
```

This will iterate over a path and zip all directories. To run above bash script in Python:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run('for i in */;  do zip -r "${i%/}.zip" "$i"; done', shell=True)
```